# Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, minidom

i have a bunch of xml files under a directory. I am trying to fetch some details out of the files such as some tag values and its last modified date  and time like that. My script is

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import os, stat
import sys
import datetime

def shahul(dir):
    for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith(".xml"):

                dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
                info=os.stat(os.path.join(r, files));
                atime=info.st_atime;
                ctime=info.st_ctime;
                mtime=info.st_mtime;
                name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
                title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
                approved_by = dom.getElementsByTagName('approved-by')
                approved = approved_by[0].attributes['approved'].value
                print (files,
                       datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(atime),
                       datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime),
                       datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime),
                       title[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
                       name[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
                       approved, sep='\t')

shahul("location")
```

Everything works fine. But the time is not valid. It shows same time for last creation time, modified time. Also in wrong format, i dont know why it is showing like this. I got the output like.

```
XXX.xml 05:49.2 05:49.2 05:49.2 File_name   E   yes
XXX.xml 22:14.6 22:14.6 22:14.6 File_name   F   yes
XXX.xml 29:15.5 29:15.5 29:15.5 File_name   E   yes
XXX.xml 16:02.1 16:02.1 16:02.1 File_name   F2  yes
XXX.xml 00:48.0 00:48.0 00:48.0 File_name   B1  yes
```

It seems not right. how to correct it?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` returns a `datetime.datetime` object. You need to call the `strftime()` method of each one to get the representation you want. I don't know why their values are all the same, however. Do you know which one, if any, of the three they all are?

Comment: you mean this sir?
print strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(files)). I tried, but got syntax error

Comment: i tried the same syntax for another file. i got the correct output. But here i am not getting

Comment: I meant `print(files, time.strftime(fmt, atime), time.strftime(fmt, ctime), ...)`, etc. -- in other word don't use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

`st_ctime` is not creation time, it is change time. You also may want to format the datetime objects using `.isoformat` or something similar.

[This](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/ctime_atime_mtime.html) might shed some light on on atime, ctime, and mtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ben. I just looked at python documentation. It said "The “ctime” as reported by the operating system. On some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time (see platform documentation for details)"